# Mail cc originating out of nowhere

Tags: email

Today a bunch of users are including a strange email address with the email addresses they're actually trying to send to and a few got through with bounce messages as follows.

> The message identifier is:     1hB5pd-0006yp-Rf
>
> The subject of the message is: Different Subjects
>
> The date of the message is:    Mon, 1 Apr 2019 22:53:34 +0000
>
> The address to which the message has not yet been delivered is:
>
> officialkennyadams@gmail.com
>
> ```
> (generated from user@thiscompany.com)
>
> host alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.128.26]
>
> Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<officialkennyadams@gmail.com>:
>
> 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
>
> 450-4.2.1 prevents additional messages from being delivered. Please resend your
>
> 450-4.2.1 message at a later time. If the user is able to receive mail at that
>
> 450-4.2.1 time, your message will be delivered. For more information, please
>
> 450-4.2.1 visit
>
> 450 4.2.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ReceivingRate k38si5896556eda.300 - gsmtp
> ```

There are no forwarders set on the CPanel server so I'm trying to work out what is happening. I can see all the WHM exim logs etc if they're any use. No one knows this address officialkennyadams@gmail.com so why is it getting copied into mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause to be CPanel email filters. So if you have a similar issue, check there first.